# Can't find .NET Framework 4.7.2 in Programs and Features?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I just install .NET Framework 4.7.2 with Web Installer. After I click restart, it update my Windows 8.1 (you know, the update screen that said "Don't turn off your PC"). Then after a long while, I can access my Windows, then I check Programs and Features and I can't find .NET Framework 4.7.2 anywhere.

I know .NET Framework 4.7.2 is installed successfully on my machine via regedit
 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`

`Release = 461814`

`InstallPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`

Why it isn't install the .NET 4.7.2 in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Multi-Targeting Pack`?

So how can I uninstall .NET Framework 4.7.2 if I can't find it in Programs and Features?

Comment: `Multi-Targeting Pack` is for the compile/design time parts of .NET. Not the *runtime* features. Unless you're a developer, you don't need the Pack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054530/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-offline-installer-for-windows):

> When you install this package, the following packages or updates are
>   installed per your operating system:
>
> In Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2, Update for Microsoft Windows
>   (KB4054566) is displayed under the Installed Updates item in Control
>   Panel.

[image: .NET 4.7.2]

I think I can uninstall .NET 4.7.2 in here.

Comment: Since when they put .NET in Updates instead of Programs?

Comment: Since .NET 4.7: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 is available on Windows Update, WSUS, and MU Catalog at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/13/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-is-available-on-windows-update-wsus-and-mu-catalog/